# Adding and removing byte from a file in a loop

Tags: c, memory, byte, entropy

I'm a security researcher and am wondering how I could remove the added bytes from a file. This function below adds a byte every 4 bytes. But I'd like to know how I could remove those bytes as well. Need a function that will remove these bytes in the order they were added.

Travis

```
int AddByte(BYTE* bIn, BYTE* bOut, DWORD dwSize, int inc_every)
{
    int increased = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dwSize; i++)
    {
        *(bOut + increased) = *(bIn + i);
        increased++;

        if (i % inc_every == 0)
            increased += 1;
    }

    return increased;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just remove a single byte from a file. You need to "shift" every byte after it to overwrite that byte. Looks like your file is memory mapped in which case one option is to use `memmove`.

Comment: Do the same thing in reverse. Copy each byte to another array, skipping every 5th byte.

Comment: Looking for an example, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Requests for code are OT. You can use something similar to what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
int RemoveByte(BYTE* bIn, BYTE* bOut, DWORD dwSize, int inc_every)
{
    int increased = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dwSize; i++)
    {

        if ((i - 1) % inc_every != 0)
        {
             *(bOut + increased) = *(bIn + i);
            increased++;
        }
    }

    return increased;
}
```

Applying this function after `AddByte()` would give back the original string. Your original function has an offset of 1 (it will skip the second byte), so this function includes the same offset

Comment: For some reason my original function starts at the second byte but your function starts at the 0 byte so it doesn't output the correct results.

Comment: @Travis, I check the code and it works as expected. My function start at byte 1 (second byte, index 1) exactly like your function. But the `inc_every` have different values for both function because after adding the bytes the string contains more bytes. Basically the `inc_every` of `remove_byte()` should be one more than the one of `add_byte()`

Comment: Alright so basically I had to use 5 (inc_every) in the RemoveBytes function and in the AddBytes function I had to use 4. This is what I was confused on. Thanks a bunch.